# Model complete theories without quantifier elimination

Tags: model-theory, quantifier-elimination

As we know, if a theory $T$ admits quantifier elimination, then $T$ is model complete. What are the simplest examples that show that the converse is not true?

Comment: For a counterexample, see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253303/quantifier-elimination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mauro indicated, I had already posted an example in a previous post. One counterexample is the theory of real closed fields in the language of rings $\{0,1,+,\cdot\}$.

It is easy to see that it does not have q.e.: the formula $(\exists x)x^2+y=z$ is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula, as you can't tell whether or not one of two algebraically independent reals is greater than the other based on their atomic diagram: swapping them around leaves the diagram unchanged, as it just says that the two satisfy no nontrivial polynomial equations.

To see that it actually is model complete is tougher. Since $\leq$ is definable (by the formula from the previous paragraph), it is enough to show that the theory of real closed fields in the language $\{0,1,+,\cdot,\leq\}$ has quantifier elimination. This is classical (AFAIK due to Tarski), and can be found in many places, for instance on page 4 (43) [of these lecture notes by Marker](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/orsay/orsay3.pdf).

Comment: Why is it enough to show that the theory in the extended language has QE ? How the definability of $\leq$ helps us here ?

Comment: @BinyaminRiahi: I wasn't entirely precise. What matters is not mere definability of $\leq$, but the fact that it is both existentially and universally definable (existential definability follows from what I wrote above, universal definability is a consequence, since $x\leq y$ is equivalent to $x=y \lor \neg (y\leq x)$). It follows that (by q.e. in the larger language) every formula is equivalent to an universal formula, which is equivalent to model completeness.

Comment: Actually after thinking about it, why isn't existential definability enough ? Given any two models $M$ and $N$ of $RCF$ (in the restricted language), if $f$ is an embedding, then since $\leq$ is existentially definable, $f$ preserves it and then by QE of $RCF$ in the extended language, $f$ is elementary. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @BinyaminRiahi: Because you need both $\leq$ and $\neg\leq$ to be preserved. Q.E. makes every formula equivalent to a Boolean combination (not necessarily positive) of atomic flas.